# T flip flop from NAND gates

Tags: flipflop, nand

I recently was interested in whether a T flip flop could easily be made from NAND gates. A google search did reveal lots of examples that basically all look like an RS flip flop with two additional NAND gates in front that combine the clock and T signals with feedback from the outputs.

Here is an example: https://www.electronicshub.org/t-flip-flop/

I have re-drawn the circuit here because I probably should not copy the figure directly into this post:

[image]

The corresponding text says:

"When the T input is HIGH and during the positive transition of the clock signal, the next state of the T flip – flop is the complement of the present state.

```
T = 1 and present state = 0, then the next state = 1
T = 1 and present state = 1, then the next state = 0
```

As each incoming trigger alternately changes the SET and RESET inputs, the flip – flop toggles."

I do understand that this is what a T flop flop does, but I cannot see how the circuit with the 4 NAND gates would do that. IMO, when T and CLK are both H, the circuit is unstable and oscillates. Adding to my confusion, there are lots of youtube videos where this NAND circuit is explained, but the explanations stop after the change has propagated 1x from left to right and ignore that after the change of the output, the input conditions are altered due to the feedback from Q and /Q to the NAND gates in the left and the circuit oscillates.

So it seems I miss something here (or all these explanations indeed are wrong ?)

Comment: I agree, this would only work if the CLK pulse is shorter than the propagation delay of two gates if at all. At a first short look to the web site you refer to, the descriptions are not correct. I might give it a second think cycle. The example using the D flipflop is funny - usually D is connected to /Q and thats all, no XOR gate.

Comment: The should be a clock edge detector to prevent the oscillation you referred to. You want there to be  just one transition with clock. The schematic as drawn does not  prevent oscillations if the clock is high for long enough.

Comment: Ok, so this confirms my suspicion that these examples and YT video explanations are wrong (or at the very least incomplete)